# Помогите с C# Ошибка CS0120

Tags: c#, winforms

Для нестатического поля/метода или свойства Form2.textBox1 требуется ссылка на объект

```
namespace diplom
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
         {
         // Cчитываем из файла сообщения
                string m = textBox1.Text;
                string k = File.ReadAllText("2.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));

                int nomer; // Номер в алфавите
                int d; // Смещение
                string s; //Результат
                int j, f; // Переменная для циклов
                int t = 0; // Преременная для нумерации символов ключа.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы скопировали этот код из консольного приложения. Метод `Main` в классе формы не нужен.

Cоздайте обработчик события `Click` для кнопки. Для этого в дизайнере вытащите из панели контролов кнопку на форму и дважды по ней кликните.

Появитя метод, в него и перенесите код из `Main`, а сам `Main` удалите.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string m = textBox1.Text;

    string k = File.ReadAllText("2.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));

    int nomer;
    int d;
    string s;
    int j, f;
    int t = 0;
    // и далее ваш остальной код
}
```

Comment: Спасибо)
Но теперь если я уберу метод Main, у меня все становится красным

Comment: @RiTick ничего не понял

Comment: Можем в соц сети пообщаться?

Comment: @RiTick вы просто посчитайте фигурные скобочки, на каждую одну открывающую должна быть одна закрывающая. Возможно вы где-то лишнюю удалили.

Comment: 98 ошибок появилось, когда убрал строку 
public static void Main(string[] args)

Comment: @RiTick я вам уже выше написал, что делать. У вас либо не хватает фигурной скобки, либо лишняя осталась.

Comment: @RiTick `когда убрал строку` не строку, а строку и все что внутри фигурных скобок за ней, надо было убрать. Начните учить C#. `{ ... }` - это блок кода, в нем располагается код. В перед открывающей скобкой идет либо сигнатура метода, либо класса. Вы возможно удалили сигнатуру, а код не удалили. Я вам сказал взять весь код изнутри фигруных скобок - перенести в новый метод, а старый `Main` грохнуть вместе со всем содержимым.

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую