# Помогите с C#. Нужно получить значение переменных из свойства

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            int nomer; // Номер в алфавите
            int d; // Смещение
            string s; //Результат
            int j, f; // Переменная для циклов
            int t = 0; // Преременная для нумерации символов ключа.

            char[] massage = m.ToCharArray(); // Превращаем сообщение в массив символов.
            char[] key = k.ToCharArray(); // Превращаем ключ в массив символов.
```

Как мне получить значения переменных m и k в метод Main

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string m = textBox1.Text;
            string k = textBox2.Text;
            

        }
```

Comment: Вам не нужно в метод `Main` ничего получать, вы просто перенесите из него код в обработчик события в `button_Click`. Выделить содержимое метода `Main` (то что между фигурным скобками) - вырезать - вставить в метод `button1_Click`. А сам метод `Main` удалите. Я уже писал вам то же самое в прошлом вашем вопросе.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1249970/373567

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите с C# Ошибка CS0120](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1249967/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-c-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-cs0120)